# The jsf2 h:outputText tag is not formating the h:outputText with the MessageFormat

Tags: jsf, internationalization, resources, facelets, jsf-2

The jsf2 h:outputText tag is not formating the h:outputText with the MessageFormat

my faces config

```
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>Messages_pt_BR</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

My resource bundle:

```
...
EventPageTitle=Event: {0}
...
```

My JSF2 XHTML:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.EventPageTitle}" >
   <f:param value="#{seuTicketEventController.selected.eventName}"/>
</h:outputText>
```

The Output:

```
Event: {0}
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?
I have searched everywhere but i can't a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) for this, not [`<h:outputText>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html).